# laravel Eloquent ORM multiple table insert

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

How would i make a single request to insert in multiple tables using laravel Eloquent ORM relationship .ie

Table 1 : users

- id
- name
- email

Table 2 : posts

- id
- user_id
- content

Table 3 : Image

- id
- user_id
- post_id
- image_name

**relationship**

1. Table `users` id  references `user_id` in other two tables .
2. Table `posts` has One To Many relation with `users`.
3. Table `images` has One To Many relation with `users` and `post` ie it can be shared with other users and on other posts.

So that when one makes a post insert ,it should insert the record in the tables with a single query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way of doing it:

```
$post = (new Post)->fill($request->all()->toArray())->user()->associate(Auth::user())->save();
```

As for the image, the `Post` model should have a model event such as `static::created` to handle the image upload and manipulation.

Or to make more sense, a model event in the `Post` model should trigger another model event from the `Image` model.

`->toArray()` may be optional, I can't test it here where I'm now.

Comment: if you would please elaborate , that will be most helpfull ?

Comment: ,what does the `associate` method do ?

Comment: It associates the user with the post, as it will properly store the id of the authenticated user into  the `user_id` field from the posts table.