# Laravel eloquent - inserting into related tables together

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I searched for this and got a lot of results and everyone says it works.

My situation is exactly the same as shown here http://laravel.io/forum/04-22-2015-hasone-and-insert

```
Schema::create('devices', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('token')->unique();
        $table->enum('type', ['android', 'ios']);
        $table->timestamps();

    });
Schema::create('students', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('nom', 15);
        $table->integer('device_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('device_id')->references('id')->on('devices')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

Student Model

```
public function device() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Device');
}
```

Device Model

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Etudiant');
}
```

And I tried

```
$student = Student::create(['nom' => $nom, 'type' => $type]);
$student->device()->create(['token' => $token]);
$student->save();
```

But i'm getting error `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::create()`
 for `$student->device()->create(['token' => $token]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

```
 $post = (new Student)->fill(['name'=>'robin'])
                ->device()->associate(Device::create(['token' => 'TOKEN']))
                ->save();
```

Reference: [laravel Eloquent ORM multiple table insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34213319/laravel-eloquent-orm-multiple-table-insert)