# Laravel updating relational table not working

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relational

> **Question 1:** Unable to update the record for relational table `profiles`. End up with the following error.

#### Error

> **Illuminate\Database\QueryException**
>   SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user_id' in 'field list' (SQL: update `users` set `user_id` = 132, `users`.`updated_at` = 2020-03-30 08:48:51 where `id` = 132)

I have two tables `users` and `profiles` with below schema

### User Schema

```
Schema::create(
    'users',
    function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('username')->unique();
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password')->nullable();
        $table->enum('role', ['super', 'admin', 'manager', 'subscriber', 'user'])->default('user');
        $table->boolean('is_root')->default(FALSE);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->unique(['username', 'email'], 'users_unique_credentials');
    }
);
```

### Profile Schema

```
Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->string('key', 191);
    $table->longText('value')->nullable();

    $table->foreign('user_id', 'profile_uid_fk')
          ->references('id')
          ->on('users')
          ->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->unique(['user_id', 'key'], 'profile_unique_key');
});
```

### User Modal - Relation

```
public function profiles()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Profile::class)->orderBy('id');
}
```

### Profile Modal - Relation

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

### User Controller - Update

```
public function update(UserRequest $request, User $user)
{

    $user->email = $request->email;
    $user->role  = $request->role;

    if ($request->has('password')) {
        $user->password = Hash::make($request->password);
    }

    $user->save();
    $user->profile()->save($user);

}
```

### dd - $request->all()

> **Question 2:** the `user_id` is a hidden field in the form. However, I would prefer to pass it from the controller instead. Is there any
>   way to do it?

```
array:15 [▼
  "_token" => "O3Ardvzz7QvAsYa7aUWn4dbJx1qpCsScykD1fh1S"
  "_method" => "PUT"
  "email" => "newage@test.com"
  "password" => null
  "password_confirmation" => null
  "role" => "subscriber"
  "first_name" => "John"
  "last_name" => "doe"
  "city" => "Ahmedabad"
  "mobile" => "545466555"
  "facebook" => "https://facebook.com/profile/pp"
  "twitter" => "https://twitter.com"
  "youtube" => null
  "instagram" => null
  "user_id" => "132"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to change query in user controller to :

```
$user->profile()->create($user->toArray())->save();
```

you can also see [this Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34213319/laravel-eloquent-orm-multiple-table-insert)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `associate` method.

`$user->profile()->associate($user);`

For more info: [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships)